# GUIStyle.Draw не реагирует на isActive == true

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вызванный `GUIStyle.Draw` с параметрами `style.Draw(rect, "Content", false, true, false, false)` рисует со стилем Normal, хотя второй параметр `isActive == true`, а значит Draw должен использовать стиль Active.

Как заставить `GUIStyle.Draw` использовать стиль Active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GUIStyle.Draw` отрисует со стилем Active только если параметры `isHover` **и** `isActive` одновременно установлены в true:

`style.Draw(rect, "Content", true, true, false, false);`

Это совершенно не очевидно, да и в документации ничего не указано. Метод научного тыка привел к такому умозаключению.